# asserting bound function calls in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have created the below angular factory named "juicefactory" and it returns the below :

```
  return {
       aj: pathbuilder.build.bind(this, 'apple', 'juice'),
       oj: pathbuilder.build.bind(this, 'orange', 'juice'), 
       mj: pathbuilder.build.bind(this, 'mango', 'juice')
  };
```

and have the below unit test cases written in jasmine.

```
before(function(){
    mockpathbuilder = {
        build: function(fruit, type) {
                  return fruit & ' ' & type;
               }
         };

 module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('pathbuilder', mockpathbuilder);
  });
});

 it('should return value from mock dependency', function () {

     spyon(mockpathbuilder, 'build');

     juicefactory['aj']();

     expect(mockpathbuilder.build).toHaveBeenCalledWith('apple', 'juice');
});
```

when debug through the code, it calls the mocked build method with two parameters but the assertion fails for some reason. Can you please help what is missing in the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a tricky issue.

### Explanation

First it's importnt to understand that `bind` returns a new function that wraps a copy of a reference to the original function with a forced context.

This is why a bound function keeps working the same way even if you redefine the original function later:

```
var pathbuilder = {
  build: function() {
    console.log('Original');
  }
};

var juicefactory = {
  a: pathbuilder.build.bind(this)
};

pathbuilder.build(); // Logs: Original

juicefactory.a(); // Logs: Original

pathbuilder.build = function() {
  console.log('New');
};

pathbuilder.build(); // Logs: New

juicefactory.a(); // Still logs: Original
```

The problem in your case is that `spyOn` will assigna new function to `pathbuiler.build`, a new wrapper function that contains a reference to the original function.

This means that all subsequent calls to `pathbuilder.build` will hit the new wrapper function created by `spyOn`, the call will be registered and then the original function will be called (if `and.callThrough()` was used when the spy was created).

However, calls to `juicefactory.a`, which was created with `bind`, will hit the original `pathbuilder.build` function and not the wrapper created by `spyOn`. This means that the call will not be recorded.

---

### Solution

One solution is to move the `spyOn(mockpathbuilder, 'build')` out of the `it` block and into the `before` where the module is created.

This basically means that when the `juicefactory` is created in the test environment and `pathbuilder.build.bind` is executed - `pathbuilder.build` will be the wrapper function created by `spyOn`, and everything will work.

Another solution is to wrap the execution of `pathbuilder.build.bind` in a function:

```
aj: function() {
  pathbuilder.build.bind(this, 'apple', 'juice')();
}
```

This will mean that the binding is done at runtime each time the `aj` function is executed. However, unless this is the functionality you actually want, I would not recommend this way. It's also worse performance wise (although most likely negligible), since the binding can happen multiple times.

Comment: I tried making the changes as per your suggestion and does not seem to work.
`    
    before(function(){
    mockpathbuilder = {
        build: function(fruit, type) {
                  return fruit & ' ' & type;
               }
         };

     spyOn(mockpathbuilder, 'build');

    module(function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('pathbuilder', mockpathbuilder);
     });
    });

    it('should return value from mock dependency', function () {

     juicefactory['aj']();

     expect(mockpathbuilder.build).toHaveBeenCalledWith('apple', 'juice');
    });`

Comment: @Ganesh Hard to say what's wrong without seeing the rest of your code. Here is a demo showing it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/aasZQgSy8DFkcAIYxJjz?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot. moving the spyOn from it block to beforeEach has solved this issue.

Comment: Good to hear :)